# Reshaping long to wide R with categorical variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like the following, with year and ID identifiers, as well as many categorical variables (values denoted with capital letters below):

```
Year   ID   Var1   Var2  Var3 ...

1996   1    A      A     B
1996   1    A      A     C
1996   2    B      A     D
1998   2    C      C     A
2000   3    D      D     D
```

My goal is to reshape this into wide format by ID, but also giving counts for ID, year, and value. So, for example:

```
ID    Var1_1996_A  Var1_1996_B  Var1_1996_C   Var1_1996_D ...

1     2            0            0             0
2     0            1            0             0
3     0            0            0             0
```

And so on, for each variable. I'm relatively new to R and couldn't quite find a similar operation from existing posts (apologies if this is duplicate). Would anyone know what the best way to accomplish this would be? I have tried using `tidyr::pivot_wider`, but can only figure out how to append the years, but not create separate categories for each variable response

```
df <- df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = year,
                values_from (Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)
```

If anyone could offer some insight that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the data in long format first :

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Var')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, Year, value), values_from = name, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#     ID Var1_1996_A Var2_1996_A Var3_1996_B Var3_1996_C Var1_1996_B Var3_1996_D
#  <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
#1     1           2           2           1           1           0           0
#2     2           0           1           0           0           1           1
#3     3           0           0           0           0           0           0
# … with 6 more variables: Var1_1998_C <int>, Var2_1998_C <int>,
#   Var3_1998_A <int>, Var1_2000_D <int>, Var2_2000_D <int>, Var3_2000_D <int>
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1998L, 2000L), ID = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), Var2 = c("A", 
"A", "A", "C", "D"), Var3 = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "D")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using base R:

```
xtabs(~ID+v, transform(cbind(df[1:2], stack(df, -(1:2))), v = paste(ind, Year, values, sep="_")))

 v
ID  Var1_1996_A Var1_1996_B Var1_1998_C Var1_2000_D Var2_1996_A Var2_1998_C Var2_2000_D Var3_1996_B Var3_1996_C Var3_1996_D Var3_1998_A Var3_2000_D
  1           2           0           0           0           2           0           0           1           1           0           0           0
  2           0           1           1           0           1           1           0           0           0           1           1           0
  3           0           0           0           1           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           1
```

Of course to transform it to data.frame you could use: `as.data.frame.matrix(...)`